# How do you create a Visual Studio Solution File (.sln) and add more projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to create Visual Studio Solution File (.sln) and add into it more than one project. 
When I add one project the (.sln) file disappear  and I can't insert other projects.

Has anybody got  any idea?

Comment: You're doing something wrong (vague answer to a vague question).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfzh36t7(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Why would you want to do this exactly?

Comment: @Adam: Solutions can (and often do) have more than one project.  Your solution will have at least two projects if you're doing unit testing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't see how this is a vague question, I've had the same issues before, when someone is acustomed to working with a single project then wants to start working with solutions and multi projects it gets confusing. And if it was vague I wouldn't of known what he needed help with which most of us i think did know what he's asking..

Comment: I agree with Andres, I think the question could have been worded much better, but doesn't deserve the close

Answer (score 7):

File -> New Project

Then Right click on Solution file , and add project

[image: Add project to solution]

Ensure that "Always show solution" is checked in the options.

[image: Always show solution, options, projects and solutions]

Comment: Something is wrong! When I try to add "new project" , the "Solution" disappear!

Comment: @BrunoFerreira if this is the solution you should mark it as "answered" http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask